# What is the main difference between AC and DC generator basic working principles?

Tags: ac, dc, generator, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

I cannot understand the main difference on AC- DC generator basic working principles.

Lets consider how a loop wire works with a magnetic flux inside a DC generator briefly. Whenever the sides of the loop wire cut the magnetic flux line there will be current occurs on those sides.

- Initial position at *0 degree*, no current because no flux lines are cut by the sides.
  [image]
- After it rotates clockwise *90 degree* the side AB comes in front of S pole and side CD comes in front of N pole. At this position, current flows from A to B on AB side and current flows from C to D on CD side.
  [image]

  - Another *90 degree clockwise*, no current on each side
  - The final rotation at *270 degree clockwise*. Here, the CD side is in front of S pole and current flows from D to C on this side. The AB side is in front of N pole and current flows from B to A on this side.
    [image]

What confuses me is that AC generator also works in this way in nutshell. What might be the difference between both of them? Talking about an AC thing there should be some sort of an "Alternating" mechanism which I can observe on the direction of the current whenever the loop wire sides come in front of different magnet poles but again a DC generator also works in this way. I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Your last drawing is incorrect. Since the coils AB/CD have switched magnets, the current is reverse of what you have, therefore an AC output. To get a DC output it is often easier to just add a rectifier. NOTE: The faster it rotates the higher the output power.

Comment: Don't you think that the current has reversed in the last picture? Have a look at the red arrows relative to the sides.

Comment: Just to make things clear. Your whole presumption that current flows is wrong; voltage is induced and, if there is a load (something connected to the slip-rings) then a current flows as a result of that induced voltage and the load resistance. Your pictures are for an AC generator and not a DC generator. Rounding up your question is pretty much flawed.

Comment: @Andy aka, I didn't explicitly mention that the slip rings in the picture are being connected to any loads nor did I ever mentioned any slip ring parts, the picture are just the simplest description of a coil inside a generator. And the picture can also describe DC generator components up to the slip rings parts.

Comment: Since the current direction is reversed in the last picture, why do you call it DC generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your illustrations show an [AC *alternator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator), rather than a [DC *generator*](https://www.electricaleasy.com/2012/12/basic-construction-and-working-of-dc.html).

An alternator may use simple contact rings (or slip rings), though if a permanent magnet spins inside a stationary stator, as on [some bicycle alternators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9FN6WRih98), no slip rings are needed.

Originally, DC generators used [mechanical commutators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_(electric)) to reverse the polarity as each pole piece passed another, changing the alternating current into "pulsating" DC. Commutators wear out more quickly than slip rings, both because of arcing on the breaking of contact and because the contact surface cannot be made completely smooth. For that reason, more reliable alternators are more commonly used to provide DC output now that solid-state rectification is efficient and inexpensive (though copper-oxide and selenium rectifiers have been used for ~100 years).

Comment: I'm still having hard time understanding it though. So overall, we cannot spot the difference if we only observe the direction of current?

Comment: The direction of current in the *windings* of alternator and generator are the *same*: both are AC. A generator that has a commutator switches the output each half-cycle, so the output is (pulsating) DC.

Comment: Thanks. you are correct. I just missed or couldn't understand some important points from your answer that is current behaviors on both generators are always alternating, it is a commutator found on a DC  generator that makes things different. It reverses the current direction to change this alternating pulse to a DC output。